# How to set each item retrieved from SQLite database into a Textview of it's own

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-sqlite

For now, I have a database with a single table having a single column of type TEXT. I want to be able to retrieve the data from that table and for each string from the table I want to insert it into it's own TextView. I want the TextViews to be arranged in vertical LinearLayout fashion. 
I know retrieved data is presented in an activity using ListView but I want separate TextView for each because I later want to set each TextView clickable and give each one some function.
Please help me with the code and tell me if any project files need to be included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

Fetch data from `Database` in `Cursor` and pass this cursor in below method it will `return` a `view` which you can pass in `setContentView(view)`

```
 public LinearLayoutCompat defaultPage(Cursor mCursor) {
        LinearLayoutCompat layout = new LinearLayoutCompat(this);

        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutCompat.VERTICAL); 
        for(int i=0;i<mCursor.getCount();i++) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            AppCompatTextView defaultText = new AppCompatTextView(this);
            defaultText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("TOUR_COLUMN_NMAE")));
            defaultText.setTextSize(20);
            defaultText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            defaultText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Work in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            layout.addView(defaultText);
        }    
        return layout;
    }
```

Comment: When I pass the layout in setcontentview(layout), it sets the entire activity layout to this LinearLayoutCompat. Can you help me if I wanted to keep a single single TextView on top of my layout intact so that whenever I use setcontentview, everything but that single TextView changes ?

Comment: then make a xml layout with parent LinearLayout and set Orientation vertical of this parent and put a textView and LinearLayout sequentially and cast textView and LinearLayout in java by findViewById() and put your lable in textView and put LinearLayoutCompat view in child LinearLayout by using LinearLayout.addView() method.