# Android dynamic buttons in java - how to define what do to with each

Tags: java, android, xml, button, dynamic

I already found something about dynamic buttons written in Java and not in XML code. It works fine but I don't know how to use those IDs for further use (going on other activity when I click them).
I know how to use method onClick when I write buttons in XML, but here I'm lost.

I got this code from https://alexanderoorayil.blogspot.si/2012/05/dynamic-button-in-android.html

**What I have so far:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
TextView t;
ScrollView scrollview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    scrollview = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    scrollview.addView(linearlayout);
    int num=15;

    if(num!=0){
    for(int i = 0; i<num;i++) {
        LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linear1);


        b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button" + i);
        b.setId(i);
        b.setTextSize(10);
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linear1.addView(b);
        }
    }
    else {
        LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linear1);

        t = new TextView(this);
        t.setText("No Buttons");
        t.setTextSize(10);
        linear1.addView(t);
    }

    this.setContentView(scrollview);
 }
}
```

**And XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/buttonList">


    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try this link, hope you will get idea from it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334532/how-to-set-each-item-retrieved-from-sqlite-database-into-a-textview-of-its-own/44334763#44334763

Comment: Thank you for your help, works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use like this**

> b.setOnClickListener(....);

```
for(int i = 0; i<num;i++) {
        LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linear1);


        b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button" + i);
        b.setId(i);
        b.setTextSize(10);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
            }
        });
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linear1.addView(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved it for me! I tried with this before but I somehow didnt manage to make it work and now it does.